# MySQL Table Backup using SQLyog

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, csv, sqlyog

I use SQLyog Ultimate v11.11. I have some tables and need to have a backup of a table's data.

I used this steps:

1. Right click on table name> Backup/Export> Export Table Data As...>
2. Selecting CSV type and name and the location of storing

and then I make a change in table content (for example: delete some records by select and delete icon in result part of Query tab)

and then I Import CSV backup file:

1. Right click on the table  name> Import CSV Data Using LOAD LOCAL...> selecting location of CSV file
2. Import the CSV file

but when I use query "SELECT * FROM " the new changes are made and I can't access my backuped data.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this document should help
 https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/Export_Database_as_Batch_Script_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm